# How to remove multiples files in bash using ssh heredoc?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I know that other users already asked the same question, but the answers didnt work for me.

I am trying to remove multiples files using an array in bash over a ssh heredoc connection, but it doesnt work dont remove any folder, however if I run the same command using ssh command it works.

How can I fix my heredoc ssh command?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -x

DIRA="/home/developer/Documents/a"
DIRB="/home/developer/Documents/b"
DIRC="/home/developer/Documents/c"

declare -a array=($DIRA $DIRB $DIRC)

ssh -T developer@192.168.0.13 <<- EOSSH
    rm -rf "${array[@]}"
EOSSH
```

Comment: What's `$(declare -f)` for? It lists all functions defined in the current environment and will execute the output, thus declaring all functions you have on your local machine on the remote machine, but you don't seem to need any of that?

Comment: I use this to be able to use my bash script functions over ssh connection

Comment: Yes, I don need, I just forget to delete it when I write this example

Comment: What error do you see? It's strange that just removing the quotes fixes it.

Comment: When I runned with quotes it doesnt shows none error message.

Comment: The problem is that the `${array[@]}` is expanded by the local shell (as it processes the here-doc), but the double-quotes aren't applied until it's parsed by the remote shell. Replace `ssh -T developer@192.168.0.13` with `cat` so you can see what's being sent to the remote end, and it should be clearer what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, its strange that just removing the quotes resolve the problem.

Comment: @GordonDavisson the output was -> rm -rf /home/developer/Documents/a /home/developer/Documents/b /home/developer/Documents/c

Comment: @ZiliomBrom Try with quotes and you'll see why it didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean quote the heredoc?

Comment: I mean try `cat` with the version that didn't work, and it'll show you *why* it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this minimal example:

```sh
arr=(a b c)

cat <<EOF
    printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
EOF
```

The output is going to be

```sh
printf '<%s>\n' "a b c"
```

which would print

```sh
<a b c>
```

If you drop the quotes,

```sh
printf '<%s>\n' ${arr[@]}
```

it expands to

```sh
printf '<%s>\n' a b c
```

and you get

```sh
<a>
<b>
<c>
```

which is why it seems to "fix" your problem, but it suffers from all the problems unquoted expansions have (word splitting, parameter expansion).

As Gordon points out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64281318/how-to-remove-multiples-files-in-bash-using-ssh-heredoc?noredirect=1#comment113671784_64281318), this behaviour is because `${arr[@]}` is expanded by the shell immediately, but the quotes in the `printf` command only apply to the result of that expansion, resulting in `printf` seeing a single argument.

To fix, you could pull the declarations into the here-doc and quote it, so the shell doesn't expand anything:

```sh
cat <<'EOF'
    arr=(a b c)
    printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
EOF
```

resulting in

```sh
arr=(a b c)
printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

which would get you

```sh
<a>
<b>
<c>
```

Applied to the specific case in the question:

```sh
ssh -T developer@192.168.0.13 <<- 'EOSSH'
    DIRA="/home/developer/Documents/a"
    DIRB="/home/developer/Documents/b"
    DIRC="/home/developer/Documents/c"

    array=("$DIRA" "$DIRB" "$DIRC")

    rm -rf "${array[@]}"
EOSSH
```

at which point you could go directly to

```sh
ssh -T developer@192.168.0.13 <<- 'EOSSH'
    rm -rf "/home/developer/Documents/a" \
        "/home/developer/Documents/b" \
        "/home/developer/Documents/c"
EOSSH
```

Comment: I need that DIRA, DIRB and DIRC be globals, so then must be defined out of ssh heredoc.

Answer (score 0):

I remove the quotes and it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -x

DIRA="/home/developer/Documents/a"
DIRB="/home/developer/Documents/b"
DIRC="/home/developer/Documents/c"

declare -a array=($DIRA $DIRB $DIRC)

ssh -T developer@192.168.0.13 <<- EOSSH
    rm -rf ${array[@]}
EOSSH
```